# How can I update Owner.Name?

Tags: apex, visualforce, update

I have the following code

```
accountToUpdate = [select owner.name from Account where owner.name = :sGetOwnerOne];
accountToUpdate.owner.name = sGetOwnerTwo;
update accountToUpdate;
```

How can I update owner names? Compiler showed me the following error:

> Field is not writeable: User.Name

I tried this:

```
Account a1 = [select owner.name from Account where owner.name = :sGetOwnerOne];
        a1.Owner.name  = sGetOwnerTwo;
        update a1;
```

But it didn't work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to change the lookup to a `User` with that `Name`? You would need to find the `User` record Id first and set `OwnerId` based on that...

Comment: I need to change the owner from one account to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Account src = [SELECT Owner.Id FROM Account where Name = 'SOURCE COMPANY'];
Account dest = [SELECT Id, Owner.Id FROM Account where Name = 'DEST COMPANY'];
dest.OwnerId = src.OwnerId;
update dest;
```

Note that the **'Id' field in the dest SOQL query is key** because Salesforce needs it to update that specific record.

Just try to replace company names with yours and you will see it happening.

I'm not sure what you have in mind but I would have done that using a list based on User objects instead of Accounts.

Also, your first SOQL statement can result in more than 1 records because you can have many accounts with a given owner.

Comment: Correct, that's excellent. But unfortunately this error is shown List has no rows for assignment to SObject why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The message "_List has no rows for assignment to SObject_" shows up when the SOQL query does not return any object. I see you based your queries on owner 's name. It's a little weird because it should be the other way around but I'll try to translate the query the way you initially designed it.

Comment: `List<Account> src = [SELECT Owner.Id FROM Account where Owner.Name = 'John'];
`
`List<Account> dest = [SELECT Id, Owner.Id FROM Account where Owner.Name = 'Mary'];
`
`if (src.size() > 0 && dest.size() > 0) {
`    dest[0].OwnerId = src[0].OwnerId;
`}
`
`update dest;
`
I'm not sure you want a mass change of ownership of Accounts or not. The APEX code above changes the owner of the dest Account but I find very unlikely that a user owns only one account.

Comment: Yes, it worked! :)

Comment: Awesome! Can you mark as the right answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the `Owner` **you can only do it by setting the `OwnerId` field**. If you want to set it based on `Name`, you will need to query for the `User` record whose `Id` you wish to set.

```
List<User> candidates = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = :someName LIMIT 1];
if (!candidates.isEmpty()) someAccount.OwnerId = candidates[0].Id;
```

If I were building a `selectList` in a controller for this purpose, I would do as @sfdcfox recommends and map `Id` to `Name`.

```
public Id newOwnerId { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> owners
{
    get
    {
        if (owners == null)
        {
            owners = new List<SelectOption>();
            for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
                SELECT OwnerId, Owner.Name FROM Account GROUP BY OwnerId, Owner.Name
            ]){
                SelectOption owner = new SelectOption(
                    aggregate.get('OwnerId'), aggregate.get('Owner.Name')
                );
                owners.add(owner);
            }
        }
    }
    private set;
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!newOwnerId}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!owners}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

Note that you would need to set `someAccount.OwnerId = newOwnerId` to use the above approach.

Comment: In the selecteList only catches me the owner.name

Comment: 1. That's not a complete sentence. 2. Your OP makes absolutely no mention of a `selectList`.

Comment: Yes, it was because SOMEONE edited my post! ><

Comment: I tried this: but it didn't work Account a1 = [select owner.name from Account where owner.name = :sGetOwnerOne];
            a1.Owner.name  = sGetOwnerTwo;
            update a1;

Comment: @RodolfoLanshore I looked through the edit history, and there has never been any mention of a `selectList` in this question before now. You may have mentioned it in another question that you've posted, but we don't have that context in this question.

Comment: @RodolfoLanshore The point is you can't set `Owner.Name`, you need to set `OwnerId`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to assign by name. Assuming you're building your select list from some sort of query, you should be able to do this:

```
SelectOption[] userOptions = new SelectOption[0];
for(User u:[SELECT Id, Name FROM User]) {
    userOptions.add(new SelectOption(u.Id, u.Name));
}
return userOptions;
```

This way, when the user selects a value, and it's assigned to sGetOwnerTwo, you'll have the user's *Id* value, which is how records are physically linked to each other. After that, you can then update your account's OwnerId value:

```
accountToUpdate.ownerId = sGetOwnerTwo;
update accountToUpdate;
```

Please note that if you're intending to query records, you should always try to query by ID values when possible. This gives better performance and ultimately makes sure you're selecting the right records (in case there's two John Does that work at your organization, you'll get the right John Doe).

Comment: But, the issue here is that I'm going to update is the ID of the user right?

Comment: What I need to do is change only the owner of one account. At selecting for example [John Lennon - account X] in the first select list  and [Michael Jordan - Account Y], at clicking the button merge, Account X will be Michael Jordan's

Comment: @RodolfoLanshore If that's the case, you'll still want to store *ID* values in your select list values. Using names is fragile, and should not be used. It sounds like your code has other underlying problems that you need to address first.